# Disable JWT exp check in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, auth0

I am authorizing `JWT` for incoming requests to spring boot application. For these requests, I would like to skip the expiry time check. Is there a provision to do the same?

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    JwtWebSecurityConfigurer.forRS256("audience", "issuer").configure(httpSecurity).authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Show your work. Edit your question and indicate what research you have done into the topic, what you have found, and why it wasn't helpful for you. You'll get more answers if you demonstrate that you've put some effort into solving your own problem. I'm not saying you didn't put any effort into it, but your question could easily be understood to indicate that you have done no research at all.

Comment: Just set your tokens to expire after a really long time when you issue them.

Comment: No, don't set the expirations to a long time unless the context here is completely understood. If the token is compromised, that becomes a serious security concern as there is no way to (easily) revoke a "by value" (eg JWT) token. Would recommend that you assess why you want to do this in the first place? Please can you share this in your question.